# Problem downloading full database in Django

Tags: python, django, database, export-to-csv, import-csv

First I used export_import to download the database but I only downloaded a single table at a time but I need to export the entire database to a file then import it back. Now I'm trying to fix it with another way I just saw using resources

If you could help me to change it to a view instead of a function I would be grateful.

Note: Thanks for the help.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .resources import CommentResource, CategoryResource

# Create your views here.
def export_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get selected option from form
        file_format = request.POST['file-format']
        comment_resource = CommentResource()
        dataset = comment_resource.export()
        print(type(CommentResource()))
        print(type(CategoryResource()))
        if file_format == 'CSV':
            response = HttpResponse(dataset.csv, content_type='text/csv')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="exported_data.csv"'
            return response        
        elif file_format == 'JSON':
            response = HttpResponse(dataset.json, content_type='application/json')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="exported_data.json"'
            return response
        elif file_format == 'XLS (Excel)':
            response = HttpResponse(dataset.xls, content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="exported_data.xls"'
            return response   
    return render(request, 'export_import_data_page.html')
```

resources.py

```
from import_export import resources
from label.models import Comment, Category

class CommentResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment

class CategoryResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
```

This is the html file to call the function to download the database
export_import_data_page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Título de mi página web</title>
   </head>
   <body>
        <div class="card card-secondary">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title">Export Comments</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form role="form" method="POST" action="{% url 'label:export_data' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Choose Format Type</label>
                        <select class="custom-select" name="file-format">
                            <option selected>Choose format...</option>
                            <option>CSV</option>
                            <option>JSON</option>
                            <option>XLS (Excel)</option>
                        </select>
                    </div> <br><br><br>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Export</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 500, unique=True) 

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.title)

class Comment(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete= models.CASCADE )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sticking this in your `views.py`

```py
import sys

from django.core.management import call_command


sysout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = open('filename.json', 'w')
call_command('dumpdata')
sys.stdout = sysout
```

Might also be worth reading up on [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata) and [call_command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code)

Edit:

You probably want to `dumpdata` with these args:

```py
call_command('dumpdata', natural_foreign=True, natural_primary=True, exclude=['contenttypes', 'auth'])
```

Comment: Hi rymanso, sorry for not responding for your help two weeks ago but I had a change in my schedule I had to do a deploy in IIS which was very difficult and took me a lot of time.

If you still want to help me, I just resumed that part of the project and when I put what you wrote in my project, I was only able to download one table at a time.